# Apple silicon Macs support issue because of SKOverlay.AppConfiguration

Tags: ios, swiftui, silicon

My app uses appStoreOverlay to show recommended app, but error occurs when submit to app store.

```
ITMS-90863: Apple silicon Macs support issue - The app uses symbols that are not present on Mac:
/System/Library/Frameworks/_StoreKit_SwiftUI.framework/_StoreKit_SwiftUI
_$s7SwiftUI4ViewP010_StoreKit_aB0F03appD7Overlay11isPresented13configurationQrAB7BindingVySbG_So22SKOverlayConfigurationCyctRQOMQ
```

I think SKOverlay.AppConfiguration is not present on silicon Mac. According to '[Building a Universal macOS Binary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/building_a_universal_macos_binary)', I add some macro and the code run in iOS only, but error still exist. Any suggestions?

```
#if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst) && os(iOS)
Button(action: { showRecommendedApp.toggle() }) { Text("App recommended".localized)  
    .appStoreOverlay(isPresented: $showRecommendedApp) {
        SKOverlay.AppConfiguration(appIdentifier: "12345", position: .bottom)
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M1 Macs can run iOS binaries directly, they don't need a Mac Catalyst build.

You can't use a #if to test for M1 at compile time since it is the same binary running on iOS and M1 Macs.

You can use a run time check of [`isiOSAppOnMac`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsprocessinfo/3608556-iosapponmac).

```
if !ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac {
    Button ...
}
```

You will still get the warning but you know that it will be handled correctly at runtime.

Comment: If the warning still exist, the app will not present in mac app store(price in connect), right? if yes, how to fix?

Comment: I believe that the warning is just that - a warning that things may not work correctly on Mac.  I don't believe that it prevents the app from appearing in the Mac app store

Comment: I don't know, I don't have a silicon mac to test it. but it's the fact in the price section of connect site.

Comment: Don't think this will work. ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac is runtime, but the program already crash when build/run on Xcode. Needs something to filter these off.